# Why is my execv() not working with 'ls' command in linux

Tags: c, linux

I'm trying to execute the command by execv() in child process (using fork()) and test the result by simple 'ls' command in linux.
However, execv does not return error(-1) but not printing anything when I input 'ls' command. I can't understand what is wrong. There are few files in directory with the c file it self containing the code so there should be some output for 'ls'
`

```
if ((pid = fork()) == 0) {
        command(argv);
        if (execv(argv[0], argv) < 0) {
        fprintf(stderr,"%s: Command not found.\n", argv[0]);
        exit(0);
        }
        exit(0);
    }
```

```
argc = 0;
    char* ptr = strtok(buf, " ");
    while (ptr!=NULL) {
    argv[argc++] = ptr;
    ptr = strtok(NULL, " ");
    }
    argv[argc] = NULL;
```

```
if (!strcmp(argv[0],"ls") || !strcmp(argv[0], "man") ||
        !strcmp(argv[0], "grep")
        || !strcmp(argv[0], "sort") || !strcmp(argv[0], "awk") ||!strcmp(argv[0], "bc")) {
        strcat("/bin/", argv[0]);
```

`

I tried changing strcat for adding /bin/ to sprintf, strcpy, but I don't think it is problem for argv[0] because execv understand the command.
may be it is error with argv but there is only /bin/ls in it. What can go wrong?

Comment: ⟼Remember, it's always important, *especially* when learning and asking questions on Stack Overflow, to keep your code as organized as possible. [Consistent indentation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Indentation_style) helps communicate structure and, importantly, intent, which helps us navigate quickly to the root of the problem without spending a lot of time trying to decode what's going on.

Comment: Tip: You may want to create a look-up table for those valid commands, like `char* allowed = { "ls", "man", ..., NULL }` to avoid creating an `if` that ridiculous.

Comment: Note: You *cannot* append to a static string like `"/bin"`. You *must* use a writable buffer. Consider: `char cmd[1024]; snprintf(cmd, 1024, "/bin/%s", argv[0])` or something similar.

Comment: `strcat("/bin/", argv[0]);` ==> BOOM SegFault -- attempting to modify read-only memory (a string-literal). `"/bin/"`is a 6-char array in read only memory `{'/', 'b', 'i', 'n', '/', \0}`.

Comment: Thank you for your comments. Now I remember that I haven't checked any result for argv[0] with /bin

Comment: In addition: No sense to check return value of `execv()`. It either return -1 or don't return at all. You can print error unconditionally after `execv()`. Also it may fail for many reasons, not necessary "command not found". Print corresponding error message, e.g.: `fprintf(stderr, "exec failed: %s: %s\n", argv[0], strerror(errno));`

Comment: @Neil `char *strcat(char *dest, const char *src);` ??

Comment: @DavidC.Rankin Ohhh I see; one is not modifying `argv`, but the string literal, and throwing away the result. Sorry about that.

Comment: @Neil - no worries -- not like I've never mixed the arguments up ... no -- who me?

Answer (score 0):

**execv()** system call ([execv() man page](https://linux.die.net/man/3/execv)) has the signature:

```
int execv(const char *path, char *const argv[]);
```

so it needs two arguments: 1) the path of the command to execute, 2) the arguments of the command to execute.

The issues in your code are:

- **argv[0]**. You're using `argv[0]` but, instead you may want to use `argv[1]`, since `argv[0]` is the name of your executable file, while `argv[1]` is the first argument from the command line. Thus, the path of the command to pass to execv() is `argv[1]`.
- The argument passed to execv() since you're passing all the command line parametes that are different to the parametes you need to send to the execv() function.

To fix your code use these lines:

```
char* arg[] = {"ls", "-l", NULL};
if ((pid = fork()) == 0) {
  if (execv(argv[1], arg) < 0) {
  ...
  }
}
```